# how come a field of my struct doesnt write out to file

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

> here is my struct that im using to send out code_name and the offset fields to the file called directory.dat

```
typedef struct country {
    char code_name[4];
    char name[45];
    int population;
    float life_expect;
    ssize_t offset;
}country;

country data[240];

static int
compmi(const void *m1, const void *m2)
       {
           struct country *mi1 = (struct country *) m1;
           struct country *mi2 = (struct country *) m2;
           return strcmp(mi1->code_name, mi2->code_name);
       }

int main(void) {

    char *swap;
    int a=0,c=0,d=0,n=0;
    int cmp = 1;
    char *ptr;
    int i = 0;
    int temp;
    char buf[512];
    char *token;
    char buf_write[10000];
    ssize_t nbytes_written; 
    ssize_t t_nbytes;

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("AllCountries.dat", "r");
    int wptr;
    wptr = open("BinaryAllCountries.dat", O_RDWR);
    FILE *rptr;
    rptr = fopen("BinaryAllCountries.dat", "r");
```

> here is the file and file pointer i am writing to

```
    int dir_ptr;
    dir_ptr = open("directory.dat", O_RDWR);

    do {
        if (fgets(buf, 512 , fptr)){
            //printf("%s\n",buf);
            token = strtok(buf,",;");
            while (token != NULL){          
            token = strtok(NULL, ",;");
                if (temp == 0){
                strcpy(data[i].code_name, token);
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("code_name: %s\n", data[i].code_name);
                }
                if (temp == 1){
                strcpy(data[i].name, token);
                cmp = strcmp(data[i].name, "Virgin Islands");
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("name: %s\n", data[i].name);
                } 
                if (temp == 6){ 
                data[i].population = atoi(token);
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("population: %i\n", data[i].population);
                }
                if (temp == 7){
                data[i].life_expect = atof(token);
                nbytes_written = write(wptr, token, strlen(token));
                t_nbytes = t_nbytes + nbytes_written;
                //printf("life expectancy: %f\n", data[i].life_expect);
                }
            temp = temp + 1;
            }
        data[i].offset = t_nbytes;
/*
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
        printf("%lu\n", offset[i]);
        printf("--------\n");
*/
        i = i + 1;
        temp = 0;
        }
    }while (!feof(fptr));

    qsort(data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]),sizeof(struct country),compmi);
```

> the problem is here when i try to write the data[i].offset it doesnt do anything and the file just consist of data[i].code_name

```
    for (i = 0; i < 239; i++){
        nbytes_written = write(dir_ptr, data[i].code_name, strlen(data[i].code_name));
        nbytes_written = write(dir_ptr, (ssize_t *)data[i].offset, sizeof(data[i].offset));
    }
```